# Is there any NLP Code for Hindi word searching?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I want NLP based search. If somebody search for onion using different language like Pyaaz, Kanda, Onion then also the result should be the same

There are only English similar word or like if pyaaz is available in database then only we can find out.

I want to search like pyaaz so it will suggest output onion same as like kandha

Comment: this is for you: https://pypi.org/project/translation/  very easy to implement

Comment: this is work if i write pyaaz in hindi like प्याज what about if i write as a Pyaaz so it will give same output as pyaaz not onion

Comment: kya aap chahte ho ke aap english mein Pyaaz likho, hindi mein प्याज nahi aur tab aapko Onion output mein milein?

Comment: use https://pypi.org/project/indic-transliteration/  then pypi.org/project/translation to obtain final output.   Like this your input will be Pyaaz, middle layer will be प्याज and the final output will be Onion.

Comment: Hi Ashu above e.g work only if i write प्याज  not in English Script like Pyaaz

Comment: I want input : Pyaaz,kanda   Output : Onion

Comment: data = 'pyaaz'  print(transliterate(data, sanscript.HK, sanscript.HINDI))   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-bb36f0bfb088> in <module>
----> 1 print(transliterate(data, sanscript.HK, sanscript.HINDI))

AttributeError: module 'indic_transliteration.sanscript' has no attribute 'HINDI'
                         Giving Above Error

Comment: I have given the code below. Please check and close the issue if it serves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was telling you in the comments above:

First your word will be transliterated and then it will be translated. 
Before running the code:

pip install these two libraries: `indic_transliteration`  and `googletrans`

```
from indic_transliteration import sanscript
from indic_transliteration.sanscript import transliterate

from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

convert = 'pyaar'

word_obtained=transliterate(convert, sanscript.ITRANS, sanscript.DEVANAGARI)
print(word_obtained)

translated = translator.translate(word_obtained, src='hi', dest='en')
print(translated.text)
```

This should serve the purpose I guess

Comment: getting error SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')",),))  I tried reinstall software plus proxy changes but not working  Even though import request

Comment: are you trying to access it from office internet?  Because office Internet connections usually have restricted access. Try it on your home machine.

Comment: Yup, It's Working on My Personal Internet Connection Thanks Bro

Comment: Also you can see my one of the program bugs of LSTM If you can Help Me?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130382/automation-in-crm-text-content  This one is about automation of crm content

Comment: @MastaneLael mark this answer as correct to close the issue. I will look into the LSTM issue as well.